How to turn on and off Bluetooth in Windows using the Windows API
I want to create a simple C++ app that programmatically toggles Bluetooth. I have successfully used bluetoothapis.h to query and list information about Bluetooth devices, but I cannot find any function that can toggle the state of it (like the WlanSetInterface function in wlanapi.h).
I know I can use the Radio Manager API or the SetupDi API but I have no idea how to.
I also read this question: Is there a way to turn on Bluetooth using winapi?, but still I don't know how I could do it.
Thank you for your help in advance!

There are 3 way to do what you need:

Use WinRT API Radio::SetStateAsync.

Internally those API uses Radio Manager that can be called directly using COM API. Take a look at the IMediaRadioManager interface. It provides access to a collection of IRadioInstance interfaces. Its SetRadioState method turns the corresponding Bluetooth radio on or off.

Direct call to the driver.



Thank you! I will take a look at IMediaRadioManager, as calling the driver could differ with different devices if I'm thinking right.

I just want to know what does radio mean? Does it include all wireless devices like Wifi, Bluetooth, Hotspot or anything or is it specifically a Bluetooth api?

@Barnabás  In case of WinRT - yes, it includes all wirelsss devices. In case of IMediaRadioManager - no. You simple call CoCreateInstance() for CLSID_BluetoothRadioManager and get it for Bluetooth Radio only. If we are talking about MS drivers then there is only one Bluetooth driver. If we are talking about Window platform than there is at least 3 Bluetooth drivers: Microsoft, BlueSoleil and Toshiba. Each has different API and if there is Toshiba installed than even WinRT Bluetooth API will not work.

@Barnabás Also note: if your app is 32 bit and you run it on 64 bit then WinRT as well as BluetoothRadioManager will not work. Your app must be 64 bit in this case.

Where can I find and use IMediaRadioManager I have found out it is located in mediadevicemanager.h but it is not in the Windows sdk. Can you please provide a small code snippet on how I could achive this?

@Barnabás Quick googling gives the second link: https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.10240.0/um/RadioMgr.idl

I don't know how I missed that Tnank you!
